# Rounding error when using INT function

Tags: excel, vba

I have user input in two cells, named "UpperRangeHigh" and "UpperRangeLow". I have the following code:

```
dRangeUpper = [UpperRangeHigh] - [UpperRangeLow]
lLines = Int(dRangeUpper * 100 / lInterval)
```

The user inputs 120.3 and 120 into the input cells respectively. lInterval has the value 10. VBA produces the result of 2 for lLines, instead of 3.

I can overcome this problem by adding 0.000000001 to dRangeUpper, but I'm wondering if there is a known reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Shouldn't the correct result be 3? 0.3*100/10=3

Comment: I suspect that you're misstating something in this question...how are you getting lLines to equal 0.2 or 0.3 when you're using the Int function? And shouldn't that function return 3?

Comment: Agree with @Ttony21 the result of the formula, per the example data you provide, should be "3", not "0.3".  `120.3 - 120 = .3`. Then, `.3 * 100 / 10 = 3`'.  I do confirm that the result of this equation appears to be `2`. Probably something to do with significant digits and rounding issues in Excel... i'll see if I can find anything else to help.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should have been 2 and 3. I'll edit my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with Excel's calculation and significant digits.  If you do:

`=120.3 - 120` and format the cell to display 15 decimal places, the result appears as:

`0.2999999999999970`

Here is a brief overview which explains how Excel uses binary arithmetic and that this may result in results divergent from what you would expect:

http://excel.tips.net/T008143_Avoiding_Rounding_Errors_in_Formula_Results.html

You can overcome this by forcing a rounded precision, e.g., to 10 decimal places:

`lLines = Int(Round(dRangeUpper, 10) * 100 / lInterval`

Answer (score 3):

Kindly use single or double when working with decimals to get more accurate results.

```
Sub sample()
    Dim dRangeUpper As Double
    dRangeUpper = CDbl("120.3") - CDbl("120")
    lLines = Round(CDbl(dRangeUpper * 100 / 10), 4)
End Sub
```

**output = 3**

[image]

Comment: This implies that a Double data type has higher precision than Long type. Is that true? Anyway, Round should be replaced by Int. I need the truncated value, not the rounded value.

Comment: @aardvark123 kindly refer to image in the answer. You can go thru the entire list from  VBA help menu search for Data Type Summary.

Comment: I know that Double has a bigger range of values. What I am trying to establish is whether the fact that the variables are casted into Doubles make the calculation more accurate?

Comment: @aardvark123 When your calculation involves decimals and you are looking for more accurate results then simply use double data type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Floating point issue within Excel

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

From MSDN:

> To minimize any effects of floating point arithmetic storage
>   inaccuracy, use the Round() function to round numbers to the number of
>   decimal places that is required by your calculation. For example, if
>   you are working with currency, you would likely round to 2 decimal
>   places:
>
> =ROUND(1*(0.5-0.4-0.1),2)

In your case, using round() instead of INT should do the trick using 0 rather than 2

Comment: `Round()` will not yield the same results as `Int()`  I.e., `=Round(6.9)` = `7` and `=Int(6.9)` = 6.  Could possibly use the `ROUNDDOWN()` function to get the same results though.