# Odd value returned by LEN in EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, precision

Consider, for example, the following function strings inside some cells:

`A1 = B1 - INT(B1)`

`A2 = LEN(A1)`

`A2` will return **17** regardless of the value returned by the function (and thus held) in `A1`. I suspect that this has to do with the precision returned by `INT(B1)`, but I don't know enough of Excel's inner-mechanisms to confirm.

The end goal is to obtain the length of the decimal part of a number held in `B1`. For example, if `B1` = **978.01194**, `A2` would hold **5** (`LEN(01194)`). Obviously this would require a subtraction of 2 to eliminate the counting of the leading (0.) in my implementation above, but that's assuming I can get proper results with this method. Any help or guidance in other methods would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT:

I realized that the loss of proper precision occurs only when I subtract the two quantities. `INT(B1)` returns proper precision, and using its length I can obtain the decimal by subtracting from the original. ***Would still like to know what is causing the operation in*** `A1` ***to lose precision internally for*** `LEN`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571911/rounding-error-when-using-int-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives are to use number that is not result from a calculation :

```
 = LEN(B1) - LEN( INT(B1) ) - 1
```

or round the number to less than [15.95 significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) :

```
 = LEN( ROUND( B1 - INT(B1), 16 - LEN(INT(B1)) ) ) - 2
```

```
 = LEN(TEXT(B1,"0.##############")) - LEN(INT(B1)) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to `FIND` where the decimal occurs and use that as an offset, e.g.

```
= LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1)
```

In general, it is not wise to perform a mathematical operation on a number when what you are really interested in is the *text* that represents the number for this exact reason. Floating points are not very reliable for dealing with exactness which is why you are experiencing the extra trailing numbers after the decimal in this case.